# Estimate the size of a cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

Can anyone provide a way to estimate the disk space that will be occupied by a cube?

For example, I've found this Excel for calculating the size of an index.
Do you know a similar way for an OLAP cube?

Comment: You haven't left any link to the Excel document you found.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the database containing the cube and choose "Reports", "Standard Reports", "General". On this report it shows the estimated size in bytes of the database. This isn't the size of the cube in isolation, but as most databases have a single cube my guess is this is the real requirement.